# My Androidproject can't connect to the Firebase dependancy

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Do anyone know how to get in touch with Firebase team? Because I've read all the other post on this topic and I'm still having this problem.... **[Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0]** I've updated and upgrading everything I could to no avail.

Comment: `firebase-database` is at 16.0.4. And the dependency is `com.google.firebase:firebase-database`, not just `firebase-database`.

Comment: I know, but every time I try to add the dependency from inside AS it always show this....app/build.gradle

    build.gradle will include these new dependencies:
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'....and then throws the aforementioned.

Comment: Never mind, it's working now! :) thanks!  I guess you dnt need the dependency to connect from with-in AS.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. This works for me Add to the build.gradle

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
```

Comment: Hi @CodeStep, Welcome to StackOverflow. It is recommended to look at the comments section before posting an answer; The original poster has already solved the problem by himself 4 months ago.